# How can I upload my local wordpress to a digital ocean droplet I have set up?

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean

I have recently finished developing my first wordpress site for a client, I have set up a digital ocean droplet and installed Wordpress (which works successfully!).

Can somebody please give me layman terms instructions on how to upload my local site to the digital ocean droplet please?

I am a beginner and struggling!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [All-in-one wp migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/#screenshots) plugin on local and droplet versions.

After the installation, click on "Export" and it will generate a .wpress file that contain code, content and database in one file.
Go to the droplet, click "Import" and drag'n drop the wpress file. Follow the instructions and update the permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner, just follow the below simple steps,
1. Create a DB in digital ocean server.
2. Move all the files to the server.
3. Edit the DB connection information in wp-config.php file with the DB data you created in step 1.
4. Export DB from your local.
5. Open the sql file and find/replace all the occurrence of local url into your live website url. You can find this url in wp_options table as site url.
6. Import the sql into the live DB which you created at step 1.

You are done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your folder structure is /var/www/html/

First, connect through SSH connection and upload the zip file to www folder.

Now install unzip

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

Now go to www by using

```
cd /var/www/
```

Extract the zip file you uploaded

```
sudo zipfilename.zip html
```

Now you need to create the database. Go to http://yourdomainname.com/phpmyadmin/

Create a DB and import the database from your local.

Change site url and home url in wp_options table with your domain url.

Now change the DB Name, Username and Password in wp-config.php file.

After that don't forget to add write permissions to the user and give write permission to your .htcaccess file.